# connect to ftp server via my android app

Tags: android, apache

I googled this a lot and I got some way to connect my ftp server: The best way is using the apache package. I'm using this code and read it from many sites but unfortunately this code is not working for me:

```
public class ApacheFTPClient extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();
        try {
            // Connect to FTP Server
            mFTP.connect("192.168.1.110");
            mFTP.login("user", "password");
            mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            // Prepare file to be uploaded to FTP Server
            File file = new File("/path/to/filetotranfer");
            FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Upload file to FTP Server
            mFTP.storeFile("filetotranfer",ifile);
            mFTP.disconnect();          
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but i get the following erros:

```
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP.connect(SimpleFTP.java:68)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at my.time.tick2.Main$8.onClick(Main.java:1585)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-28 18:48:12.018: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what is the problem? my ftp server is running well and I can access it with anonymous or any username in server from anywhere. my ftp server is ok.

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException + search box = solution. please do that before asking next time.

Comment: what are tease meaning? what i have to do? u mean i have put this codes on asynctasc or somthing like?

Comment: try to search before posting a new question. You must separate any download action from the UI thread to avoid blocking your application, you have to move the download to an AsynTask and update ui when the task is complete.

Comment: tnx guys. i'm sorry but i search more and more. now i have a solution because your help and i thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as njzk2 said i place my code in asynctasc and my problem solved. thanks every body